# Use of accumulator in main

Tags: haskell, program-entry-point, accumulator

I want to use an accumulator in the main.

Lets say:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Hey there, what's your name and age?"
   name <- getLine
   age <- getLine
   putStrLn ("Hi " ++ name ++ " you are " ++ age ++ " years old!")
   main
```

So what I want to do is if the user did not supply his name and just the age, I want to use the age that was entered before in the next main call. Any suggestion how I can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

sure just use another function where you can use arguments of your choice:

```
ask :: String -> IO ()
ask lastAge = do
   -- don't know what you want to do with lastAge
   -- so I just use it when the user did not enter anything
   putStrLn "Hey there, what's your name and age?"
   name <- getLine
   age' <- getLine
   let age = if null age' then lastAge else age'
   putStrLn ("Hi " ++ name ++ " you are " ++ age ++ " years old!")
   ask age

main :: IO ()
main = ask ""
```

---

allow me to introduce a small improvement: you probably don't want the infinite loop here - you can get rid of it easily using [unless](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:unless):

```
import Control.Monad (unless)

ask :: String -> IO ()
ask lastAge = do
   -- don't know what you want to do with lastAge but here you have it
   putStrLn "Hey there, what's your name and age?"
   name <- getLine
   unless (null name) $ do
     age' <- getLine
     let age = if null age' then lastAge else age'
     putStrLn ("Hi " ++ name ++ " you are " ++ age ++ " years old!")
     ask age
```

this will stop the loop as soon as the user does not give his name

Comment: Thanks for your help but thats not what I want. If I don't enter a name and just the age there should be no output. Then when I enter a name and age next time the output should be the entered name and the age that was entered before.

Comment: well tbh: I don't know exactly what you are trying to do (your question stated otherwise) - but the snippet should be easy to adapt - you only asked for a way to use *an accumulator* - and I just wanted to show you how to do it with just an function-argument

Comment: It's just a programming task. There is a hint that says, you can use an simple accumulator rather than a monad.

Comment: oh I think I spoiled your homework then (sorry) - anyway: one more reason for you to try it yourself (and you cannot escape the `IO` Monad/Type here as you want to input and output data)